# Ubuntu phone in 2019

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, ubuntu-edge

do you have some informations about Ubuntu phone at the moment?

I saw few articles about Ubuntu Edge but I thought that it is dead.
Also I saw for UBPorts with Ubuntu Touch.

I was really interested for project Ubuntu Edge. So my question, is there some idea of ubuntu phones in 2019 or everything is dead?

Answer (score 10):

Ubuntu Edge was a project that failed to meet crowdfunding requirements. You can find the whole story on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Edge)

Canonical has stopped its official support to [Ubuntu Touch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Touch) (the OS dedicated to phones) in 2017. The code is now maintained by the [UBports](https://ubports.com) community. As far as I know it is not possible to buy an Ubuntu phone, if you wish to install it you'll have to purchase a phone and make the installation yourself. [Some phones](https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io/) are supported by UBports. I never gave a try myself as the maintained phone are difficult to find or over expensive in my opinion. But the UBports community is alive and delivers regular updates.

Some projects of open source phones are normally coming, such as [Purism Librem 5](https://puri.sm/products/librem-5/), [PinePhone](https://www.pine64.org/pinephone/) or [Necuno](https://necunos.com/). I follow them regularly as I hope it will be possible one day to install Ubuntu Touch on one of them.

**2020 update**
The [PinePhone](https://www.pine64.org/pinephone/) project has progressed recently. It is now possible to pre-order a PinePhone with [UBports](https://ubports.com) installed :) You can have a look into [Pine64 Store](https://store.pine64.org/?product=pinephone-community-edition-ubports-limited-edition-linux-smartphone) to know a bit more about it and decide if you want to give it a try.

Comment: I hope one day for _convergence_ when all my devices will be Ubuntu... but maybe that's just a pipe dream...

Comment: Convergence is already a thing, Ubuntu Touch supports it, and can be done with some devices, some devices just don't have what it takes for it.