# Install terminal after factory reset

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch, phone

I had to do a factory reset on my bq Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition and all my apps, including terminal, were deleted. I am unable to do it from the Ubuntu Store from Canonical since it is closed. ¿Is there any alternative way I can install a terminal? This is what I tried so far:

I downloaded the app from https://open-store.io/app/com.ubuntu.terminal
And tried to instal it using adb shell and running the command:

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~/Downloads$ pkcon install-local --allow-untrusted com.ubuntu.terminal_0.9.2_armhf.click
```

but I get the following output:

```
Installing files              [=========================]         
Finished                      [=========================]         
Installing files              [=========================]         
Waiting for authentication    [=========================]         
Starting                      [=========================]         
Finished                      [=========================]         
Fatal error: /home/phablet/Downloads/com.ubuntu.terminal_0.9.2_armhf.click failed to install.
WARNING:root:Signature check failed, but installing anyway as requested
Cannot install /home/phablet/Downloads/com.ubuntu.terminal_0.9.2_armhf.click: 
Framework "ubuntu-sdk-16.04" not present on system (use --force-missing-framework option to override)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu phone in 2019](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131017/ubuntu-phone-in-2019)

Comment: You will need to re-flash your phone using the UBports installer to switch over to the community maintained Ubuntu Touch on your phone and continue getting updates. The old Canonical version is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your kind comments. Of course I will need to install the supported Ubuntu Touch eventually, but in case anyone needs a quick, provisional solution, I found this page

http://cdimage.ubports.com/clicks/

from where I was able to download old .click files for the terminal and other apps that worked in the outdated version.

Comment: Flashing the device using the UBports Installer is best and fastest way to do what you want.